# unable to reach request mapping endpoint so im getting 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I created a new controller with request mapping "/route" but no matter whatever i do I am unable to reach the endpoint `localhost:8080/route`. I always get 404.

How can I access the endpoint route without getting 404?

```
@RestController
public interface RouteController {
@ApiOperation(value = "Add a route details to adapter", nickname = "addroute", notes = "Add route details to the table and Send it to ATLAS", tags = {
        "route", })
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful Insertion into DB and Proceded for Transformation"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid Input") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/route", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = {
        "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createData(
        @ApiParam(value = "Route Array", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody RouteArray routeArray) ;
}
```

**Implementation class**

```
public class RouteControllerImpl implements RouteController {

@Autowired
private RouteService routeService;


@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> createData(@ApiParam(value = "Route Details", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody RouteArray routeArray) {

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(routeService.transformRoute(routeArray));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you check your application context path? (You can find it in your console log)

Comment: Annotations aren't working on interfaces. Try moving all your annotations to `Impl` class

Comment: org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils: POST "/route", parameters={}
springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping: looking up handler for path: /route
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping: Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler: Resource not found
FrameworkServlet: Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a few things in your implementation. You should not use @RestController with your OpenAPI api, but rather use @Api annotation. You should use @RestController on the class implementing this API.

```
@Validated
@Api(
    value = "route",
    description = The Controller API"
)
public interface RouteController {
@ApiOperation(value = "Add a route details to adapter", nickname = "addroute", notes = "Add route details to the table and Send it to ATLAS", tags = {
        "route", })
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful Insertion into DB and Proceded for Transformation"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid Input") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/route", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = {
        "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createData(
        @ApiParam(value = "Route Array", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody RouteArray routeArray) ;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@RestController
public class RouteControllerImpl implements RouteController {

@Autowired
private RouteService routeService;


@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> createData(@Valid RouteArray routeArray) {

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(routeService.transformRoute(routeArray));
}
```